# How to deploy on AWS Lambda with Zappa through Git

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, zappa

I am looking for ways to deploy on AWS Lambda with ZAPPA through my github repository. I couldn't find any videos or blogs about this. Does anyone know

Answer (score 2):

Aside from digging deeper as to how AWS Lambda works, checkout [AWS CodeBuild](https://aws.amazon.com/codebuild/) and [AWS CodePipelilne](https://aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/).

You can trigger build whenever you push changes to your github repository depending on your setup of `source` in your pipeline step. Link your github repository on the step.

The CodeBuild part serves as your environment that builds the project. I'm assuming zappa is only one of the tools you're using to deploy, you can add that as part of the stages/phases of buildspec required to build the application or maybe just download the requirements of your application and/or uploads them to s3, which then be the source code of which your Lambda function will refer to.